# Modify Tree of Work Items query in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

I have a Tree of Work Items query in TFS 2013 which show us all closed requirements with not closed or not ready bugs, requirements, tasks, test cases or reviews, i.e. not correct requirements. I have result like this:

|-- Requirement 1
|-- Requirement 2
|-- Requirement 3
|-- -- Task 1 (state = 'Closed')
|-- -- -- Bug 1(state = 'Proposed')
|-- Requirement 4
...
So i see requirement 3 which have task 1 with proposed bug 1. How can I modify my query to see only requirement 3 without another requirements? It can be not only Tree of Work Items.

Answer (score 0):

Just try checking if `Related Link Count` field can work for you.

Comment: Another requirements also have links but they 'state' is closed or ready. That's why we don't see related link in other requirements.

Comment: If you mean Requirement 1, 2 4 also are not correct requirements and they too have linked work items and your query is showing them all then I don't think there is a possibility. You can try adding additional filters to your query but I don't think it would make sense.

Comment: Yes but it's kind of my task. I was told that it's possible. I need modify this query. It can be not only Tree of Work Items. In result it have to be only incorrect requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Check the screenshot below, choose `Match linked work item first`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer and example. I tried to make this query but there is no direct link between requirement and bug cause also have a task :)

Comment: In my example, you can see I got the link between requirement and bug. As Task 1 was Closed, it won't show in the query result.

Comment: Ok, in my case i haven't link between bug and requirement. If i add link, it won't be incorrect? Sorry for this question but i need understand it

Comment: Yes, but it's okay :) There is a kind of solution, I also tried this, but I have very big project, so there is a lot of another links which not related to requirements. When I need only incorrect requirements :)

Comment: Could you give an example of your requirement?

Comment: Requirement? Here a [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/ck7c4s) where we see two linked items. It's our "Task" and "Bug", another top-level links are bugs or something else which relate to active requirements.

Comment: OK , I got your point. This query also shows the linked work items to a not closed Requirement..I'm afraid TFS query won't be able to give you a perfect result. It would either show the closed top-level Requirement which has linked work items, or the linked work item to a not closed Requirement. You need either add other clauses, or use api to retrieve the data.

Comment: Yes, I think that I need to use api for this case. I still try add other clauses, but most likely it will be api. Thank you for your help